# Why is TSC larger in VirtualBox when I enable "TiedToExecution"?

Tags: timer, virtualbox

**Background (my understanding of how rdtsc is virtualized):** I am experimenting with TSC values in VirtualBox. My current understanding of how VirtualBox emulates `rdtsc` is that in virtual mode, any call to rdtsc will be offset by a predetermined result, which is a value set in another register. This value would be `rdtsc` on the host when the virtual machine started.

An advantage to this strategy is that `rdtsc` will advance with wall clock time in an expected manner, but the disadvantage is that a process may perceive `rdtsc` to take longer than expected. For instance, in simple code like this:

```
x = rdtsc();
y = rdtsc();
z = y - x;
print z
```

executed on the guest, `z` may be larger than expected because of the wall-clock-time cost associated with trapping rdtsc. It would be even worse if the host OS swapped off the VirtualBox process in between these two calls.

From reading the VirtualBox manual (Change TSC Mode), I read there is an alternative virtualization technique which is supposed to directly simulate TSC. As I understand it, the offset value will only take into account time that the guest OS actually uses the CPU. The advantage is that with respect to cycles available, TSC will behave exactly as if it was on a host machine. The downside is that TSC will drift away from wall-clock-time as there are "missing cycles" that the guest OS is not aware of.

**My goal:** I am trying to set VirtualBox to do the 2nd option. I want to emulate the short-term behavior of rdtsc as if it were running in hardware as precisely as possible, and I don't care if it doesn't match wall-clock-time. I am fully aware that this is not "reliable" on SMP; it's for experimenting not for enterprise software.

**What I did:** First I wrote a simple test program that calls `rdtsc` repeatedly, then prints the results:

```
__inline__ uint64_t rdtsc()
{
    uint32_t lo, hi;
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("rdtsc" : "=a" (lo), "=d" (hi));
    return (uint64_t)hi << 32 | lo;
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    uint64_t val[8];

    val[0] = rdtsc();    
    val[0] = rdtsc();
    val[0] = rdtsc();
    val[0] = rdtsc();
    val[0] = rdtsc();
    val[0] = rdtsc();
    val[0] = rdtsc();
    val[0] = rdtsc();

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        printf("rdtsc (%2d): %llX", i, val[i]);
        if (i > 0) {
            printf("\t\t (+%llX)", (val[i] - val[i - 1]));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried this program on my host machine. Then, I ran it in my VirtualBox machine. The deltas between `rdtsc` were essentially identical -- the only difference was the value itself on my host was about 30T more. Example output:

```
rdtsc ( 0): 334F2252A1824
rdtsc ( 1): 334F2252A1836    (+12)
rdtsc ( 2): 334F2252A1853    (+1D)
rdtsc ( 3): 334F2252A1865    (+12)
rdtsc ( 4): 334F2252A1877    (+12)
rdtsc ( 5): 334F2252A1889    (+12)
rdtsc ( 6): 334F2252A18A6    (+1D)
rdtsc ( 7): 334F2252A18B8    (+12)
```

Then, I changed the `TSCTiedToExecution` flag in VirtualBox, which I thought was supposed to ignore wall-clock-time in favor of more precise virtual cycle counting. I got this from the manual page I mentioned above:

```
./VBoxManage setextradata "HelloWorld" "VBoxInternal/TM/TSCTiedToExecution" 1
```

However this gave me unexpected results. The virtual program now returned:

```
rdtsc ( 0): F2252A1824
rdtsc ( 1): F2252A1836   (+B12)
rdtsc ( 2): F2252A1853   (+B1D)
rdtsc ( 3): F2252A1865   (+AFF)
rdtsc ( 4): F2252A1877   (+B13)
rdtsc ( 5): F2252A1889   (+AF2)
rdtsc ( 6): F2252A18A6   (+B1D)
rdtsc ( 7): F2252A18B8   (+B0C)
```

With `TSCTiedToExecution` on, rdtsc seems to be taking about 1100 cycles to execute....

**Question:** First, I am wondering why did I get this behavior? It seems like almost the opposite of what I would expect, and it certainly does not match with my understanding of how this is implemented.

Second, I am wondering how can I accomplish my original goal of having TSC advance for each virtual cycle as if it was on hardware?

**My Setup:** I am running on a 8x Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5550 @ 2.67GHz. VirtualBox has VMX and nested paging enabled. I compiled it from source, version: 4.1.2_OSE r38459.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I started a bounty on this, but still no answers...

Answer (score 0):

To make self crying try to disable "VBoxInternal/TM/TSCTiedToExecution" and run your test program again. The next code

```
ULONGLONG x1 = Cpu::Rdtsc();
ULONGLONG x2 = Cpu::Rdtsc();

DbgPrintUlong('D', x2 - x1, 30, 23);
```

running on VirtualBox with "VBoxInternal/TM/TSCTiedToExecution" disabled display that x2 - x1 took about 200 000 of cycles. In contrast, on machine with "VBoxInternal/TM/TSCTiedToExecution" enabled it took only 3 000 jf cycles. I think, this reduction is meant by next passage from the VirtualBox manual "In special circumstances it may be useful however to make the TSC (time stamp counter) in the guest reflect the time actually spent executing the guest."

So, I think we won't have better TSC emulation in VirtualBox for a long time.

The only thing that I can advise is to move on VmWare Workstation. It have much better emulation of TSC.